# How do you add tags to data-driven tests in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to add tags to data-driven tests in Robot Framework. I have created keywords for the templatized tests and tables for the data similar to the following:

```
# Test case file
*** settings ***
Resource       libraries.txt
Test Template  My Test Template

*** test cases ***       parameter1   parameter2  ER
testa                    value1a      value2a     ERa
testb                    value1b      value2b     ERb
```

---

```
# Template file
*** Keywords ***
My Test Template
  [Arguments]  ${parameter1}  ${parameter2}  ${ER}
  ${result}=  Do Something  ${parameter1}  ${parameter2}
  Should Be Equal As Strings  ${result}  ${ER}
```

How can I add (possibly distinct) tags for testa and testb?

---

It turned out to be PEBKAC. I was not indenting the tag statement. Those double spaces did me in (again).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to add a tag.

Only test specific is like:

```
*** Test cases ***
Test A
  [tags] tagA tagB
  Log  This is test A
```

It is possible to add a tag to all testcases in your file by placing a `Force Tags` in your settings:

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags  NewTag
```

For more information you can check the user guide: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases

Comment: This question is specifically asking about data-driven tests, which your answer doesn't address.

Comment: The answer is not talking about data-driven.

Comment: The link is broken (because [Google Code itself shut down in 2016](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)).

Comment: Indeed, the link is now http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases

Answer (score 11):

Tags can be added like this:

```
*** test cases ***       parameter1   parameter2  ER
testa                    value1a      value2a     ERa
    [Tags]    tag1
testb                    value1b      value2b     ERb
    [Tags]    tag1
```

Comment: D'oh! Done in by those pesky indents. I had the square bracket right under the test name rather than two spaces in.

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to modify your keyword to take tags as arguments. Then you could do something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Test Template | My Test Template

*** test cases ***       
| testa | value1a  | value2a | ERa | tag1 | tag2
| testb | value1b  | value2b | ERb | tag2 | tag3

*** Keywords ***
| My Test Template
| | [Arguments] | ${value1} | ${value2} | ${er} | @{tags}
| | log | value1: ${value1}
| | log | value2: ${value2}
| | log | er: ${er}
| | Set tags | @{tags}
```

When run, testa will have the tags `tag1` and `tag2`, and testb will have the tags `tag2` and `tag3`